# New Trigger type not appearing when creating promotions

Tags: smarttarget

I have added a new Audience Manager extended detail to the trigger-types.xml configuration file of my Fredhopper index server as described [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-3FA82432-47BF-4B6F-A3F5-96E783233F8F). After restarting the Fredhopper instance, I do not see the new trigger type when creating promotions using the SmartTarget  (2014 SP1) UI. Is there something that needs to be restarted/refreshed?

Note that when I request the trigger types directly from Fredhopper with the URL:

http://myserver:8180/fredhopper/config/trigger-types

the updates are not shown, so something is wrong here

Comment: Hi Will! Do you see the new trigger in the Business Manager UI (fredhopper UI)? Can you paste the relevant part of your trigger-types.xml?

Comment: I just added a simple text Trigger and after restarting FH I could see it appear right away in FH business manager, ST 2014 SP1 Targeting UI and "/fredhopper/config/trigger-types". So nothing special to do on my side. Maybe try with a simple text trigger first.

Comment: Thanks Phil - that doesnt work either - I have the feeling that I am restarting the wrong thing. I am following the documentation though - running bin/instance MyIndexInstanceName -stop and then -start. The weird thing is that even after I stop the index instance, I can still make requests on port 8180 - is this expected?

Comment: That depends on whether the index instance is instance #1. It does sound like you are restarting the wrong instance, though.

Comment: I also restarted the query instance to be sure, and that didnt help... Would stopping the index instance normally shut down the application running on port 8180, or is there some container application which the instances run in?

Comment: Did you install the FH extension: configuration-management-rest-extension-<version>.jar? see http://bit.ly/16Z1EJn

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple solution: The syntax to shutdown start the FH instance (on Linux) should be

```
bin/instance MyIndexerInstanceName stop
```

(I was using `-stop`)

Theres no feedback when you provide the command, so the instance was not actually stopping, thus still available and with cached trigger types.